# C# DateTimeの精度

Tags: c#

時間ではなく時刻での時間計測をミリ秒単位で行いたいのですが、DateTime.Now.Millisecondの精度はどのくらい保障されているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

無論ローカルシステムの時刻が正確であるかどうかは保証されていませんが、メソッドとしての`DateTime.Now`の解像度は.NET 4.5系では[15ms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)、それ以前では[Windows NT系で.10ms、Win9xで55ms程度](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.100).aspx)とされています。

また`DateTime`型の仕様上の精度は100ナノ秒単位です。

Answer (score 1):

時刻同期や時刻調整の影響を受ける為、そもそも精度の保障はないと思います。